# Looking to fix slow (0.42Mbit/s) upload speed on personal hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hotspot, ubuntu-22.04

Webpages are either not loading at all, or taking very long to load which I believe has to do with very slow upload speed:

```
Testing download speed..................................................
Download: 198.87 Mbit/s 
Testing upload speed....................................................
Upload: 0.42 Mbit/s
```

On Windows partition the upload speed is ~20 MBit/s with the same hotspot.

Output of iwconfig on my hotspot:

```
wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"jwielink\xE2\x80\x99s iPhone"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: 46:FC:F1:9B:B5:11   
          Bit Rate=1.2009 Gb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-29 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with MT7921 wireless network adapter, I have no trouble with the upload speed when I'm connected to home WiFi.

So I've ruled out any issues with the hotspot itself, and on home WiFi no issues either, I tried setting my hotspot to 2.4GHz which didn't resolve the problem.

What else can I try to fix my upload speed?

Comment: I did. I have Windows dual-boot, on the Windows partition speed is fine.